# Automatically sharing notebook/getting public URL?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Is there some utility that'll let me share current notebook to Wolfram Cloud and get public URL?

My current workflow for sharing is to make a temporary copy of notebook locally, then save it to cloud, then open it in browser and copy public link from sharing settings. I need to make a temporary copy because I noticed the public link becomes invalid if I edit the notebook and save it again in Mathematica.

Comment: I suppose I can solve public URL invalidation if I save notebook to cloud, and then never edit it again

Comment: I don't have much experience with the cloud functions, but from my reading of the documentation it should work to use `CloudDeploy` on a notebook object (that you can retrieve with `Notebooks[]`). It will return a URL. Since it is a deployed object, it shouldn't have any kind of connection with the local notebook AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do something like what I wanted using `CloudDeploy[Notebooks[][[3]], Permissions -> "Public"]`

Answer (score 1):

PS, after some trial an error I ended up with function below which I'm mostly happy with. Usage is --
 execute `deploy`, it'll print timestamp and link which is public, also copied into clipboard for convenience. This deployment is a snapshot, so calling `deploy` multiple times will deploy new copies of the object.

Some lessons learned:

- Exporting object, then editing it in cloud invalidates the public URL link (the link will start prompting user to sign in), hence must export snapshots and never edit them.
- Using notebook filename as name for cloud object will overwrite previous results, so generate unique names by appending timestamp to filename.

Code

```
(* Deploys current notebook, returns URL object *)
(* TODO: add support for notebooks with no name (current gets StringSplit failed) *)
deploy:=Module[{result,notebookPath,notebookFn,uniqueFn,url,url2},
(* print out machine name + path + date *)
notebookPath=$MachineName~StringJoin~":"~StringJoin~NotebookFileName[];
notebookFn=FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[]][[-1]]; (* just get basename *)
notebookFn=dropExtension[notebookFn];
uniqueFn=StringJoin[notebookFn,"_", timeString, ".nb"];
Print[notebookPath];
Print[DateString[]];
(* todo, also update master copy in cloud and link to it using SourceLink? *)
result=CloudDeploy[SelectedNotebook[],CloudObject[uniqueFn],Permissions->"Public",SourceLink->None];
url=result[[1]];
url2=URLShorten[url];
CopyToClipboard[url2];
url2
];
```

Comment: You can also deploy using your username. e.g. `CloudDeploy[xxx, "user:b3m2a1/path/to/file"]`. That will then give you the public URL.