# Where are my Cloud Credits going?

Tags: wolfram-cloud

In less than a month I've used 5k cloud credits (half of my quota) and all I did was deploying a bunch of static notebooks with `CloudDeploy[CurrentNotebook[],permissions->Public]` (more specifically, [deploy](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144917/217) function)

Wolfram usage [dashboard](https://www.wolframcloud.com/app/dashboard) shows "0 credits used" for every category. Going to Mathematica Online/Deployments shows no deployments under all categories.

I've contacted Technical Support, and they just referred me to "Cloud Credits" [page](http://www.wolfram.com/cloud-credits/) which lists costs of various things, none of which I'm using.

Any suggestions how to figure out where my cloud credits are going?
(on a related note, I have no idea how much space I'm using against my 10GB quota, `CloudAccountData[]` shows 0 usage, which seems low)

Comment: `$CloudCreditsAvailable`

Comment: The issue with cloud credits has [been a beef of mine](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109259/7167) for over a year.  WRI doesn't seem to have a good handle on appropriate usage yet.

Comment: @yode that just gives me number of credits available. What's missing is why. I suspect that what happened is 1) Deploying static pages costs credits or 2) Viewing static pages costs credits 3) There's some dynamic component being executed and "leaking" credits, so I should find a way to track it down and kill it

Comment: `CloudAccountData[]`